# Python round calculator

Tags: python, int, rounding

Hey i'm a little noob still but i'm playing around with python and i want  to round **D** to it's nearest decimal, **C** and **H** are fixed and **D** is the rawinput, the whole answer should be rounded but i keep getting decimals,i want this formula :

> **Q = Square root of [(2 * C * D)/H]**

her's my code:*

```
import math

C=50
H=30
D=int(raw_input())
a=int(round(D))

Q= math.sqrt(2*C*a/H)
print Q
```

if i enter **100** i get **18.24**

i just want it to be **18**

i would really appreciate your help, *thanks*

Comment: So then convert it?

Comment: You're only rounding the input number, not the result `Q = int(round(Q))`

Comment: `print round(q)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

C = 50
H = 30
a = int(raw_input())

# prints as a float
# Q = round(math.sqrt(2 * C * a / H), 0)

# prints as an int
Q = int(round(math.sqrt(2 * C * a / H), 0))

print Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be rounding in the wrong place. You're rounding the input `a`, which was already the integer `D`. You're not rounding the result of the square root `Q`, which is a float.

Note that you're code actually has an extra rounding step you may not intend in it. When you divide two integers in Python 2, you'll get another integer, even if the computation should have had a remainder. You get floor division, always rounding towards negative infinity, not to the nearest integer (so e.g. `9/10` is `0`). In your code, `2*C*a` is an integer, since all values you're multiplying are, and so when you divide by `h` (another integer), it's going to round the division off. In the case you gave where you entered `100` as the user input, you'll get `333` as the result of the division instead of the more precise `333.3333333333333`. This in turn makes your square root calculation give a different value (`18.24828759089466` instead of `18.257418583505537`).

Anyway, you probably want to use floating point values everywhere except *maybe* at the end when you round off the value before printing it. You almost certainly don't want to be using integer math by accident as your current code does. One way to do that is to turn one of your constant values into a float, and move the rounding to the end:

```
C=50.0                              # make the calculations use floats, rather than ints
H=30
D=int(raw_input())                  # no need for `a` anymore, we're rounding later instead
Q= int(round(math.sqrt(2*C*D/H)))   # round after taking the square root, not before
```

An alternative to using `C=50.0` is to put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file, which tells Python that you want division between integers to return a `float`. That's the default behavior in Python 3, and it's much nicer most of the time. If you specifically want "floor" division, you can explicitly ask for it with the `//` operator. You might also consider actually using Python 3, rather than making do with Python 2's forwards compatibility features.